# Free variables and bound variables

Tags: analysis

In Terence Tao's Analysis I (page 321-322), he says

$ 1.\quad $ On the other hand, the statement $(x + 1)^2 = x^2 + 2x + 1$ is true for every real number $x$, and so we can regard this as a true statement even when x is a free variable.

$ 2.\quad $   One can also turn a free variable into a bound variable by using the quantifiers “*for all*” or “*for some*”. For instance, the statement $(x + 1)^2 = x^2 + 2x + 1$ is a statement with one free variable $x$, and need not have a definite truth value, but the statement $(x + 1)^2 = x^2 + 2x + 1 $ for all real numbers $x$ is a statement with one bound variable $x$, and now has a definite truth value (in this case, the statement is true).

My question is: Is not the statement $(x + 1)^2 = x^2 + 2x + 1 $ true for every real number no matter it's free or bound vaiable? Why does the free variable $x$ turn into a bound variable when we add *for all* stuff? I mean, *for all* means the $x$ is still free, right?  Thank you!

Comment: If $x$ can be any exotic object, the equality might be false. But for every "reasonable" input of $x$ , the equation is true. One should define what $x$ can be at all before talking about universal truth.

Comment: Using [my answer to your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4658998/21813) as an example: in rewriting $x^2=4 \implies \exists x \;(x=2\land x^2=4)$ as $x^2=4 \implies \exists y\; (y=2\land y^2=4),$ notice that the free variable may be called/referred to elsewhere, so cannot be renamed, whereas the bound variable can be renamed, because its scope doesn't extend outside its quantifier's boundary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, we say that a variable is bound when there is a $\forall$ or a $\exists$ repeating this letter before it. In order to have a better grasp about this, try substituting variables. Consider, for example, the sentence $(\forall x, x = x+1) \Rightarrow x = 0$. If you change the last $x$ by $y$, the sentence becomes $(\forall x, x = x+1)\Rightarrow y = 0$ and has a different meaning: the first *talked* about someone named $x$, and the second *talks* about someone named $y$. Try substituting one of the $x$ before, in a messy way: we can get, for example, $(\forall x, y = y+1)\Rightarrow x = 0$. Now, this sentence *talks* about some $x$ and about some $y$, so its meaning is different. However, if you substitute all occurrences of the letter $x$ within the *scope* of the quantifier, you get the equivalent sentence $(\forall y, y = y+1) \Rightarrow x = 0$.

The fact that a variable is bounded or not is purely syntaxical, has nothing to do with truth whatsoever, and does not even depend of the *meaning* of the quantifier! The boundedness of a variable is really just a notation to express that some occurrences of a variable may be substituted without changing the meaning of the sentence and some other occurrences may not.

A final advice: you keep talking about *truth*, but you should really think about *provability*.

We can give a truth value to the sentence $(x+1)^2 = x^2 + 2x +1$ only if we give meanings to the symbols $+$, $^2$, $1$, $2$, and, of course, $x$. However, this sentence is provable, if we assume some hypotheses (for example, assuming $+$ is *associative*, that $^2$ denotes the multiplication by something by itself, that multiplication distributes over $+$, etc.). At this level, the real point of learning the logical rules is to teach you grammatical rules of a language, not what the sentences mean.

Comment: Sorry to bother,but why $∀x [(x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1]$ the $x$ is bound while in $(x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1$ the $x$ is free?

Comment: By definition of boundedness. If $x$ is free in $P$, then it is bound in $\forall x , P$.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that "free variable" just means a variable not quantified, while "bound variable" is a variable quantified over certain set.

You say: the statement $(x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1$ is true *for every real number* $x$. But by saying "for every real number", you are quantifying like saying $∀x∈\mathbb R\ ((x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1)$. So your  variable isn't free anymore. But "bound" doesn't mean exactly what you thing, in this case it's just a way to say that it's bound to belong to the real line.

In fact, you might construct some algebraic structure in which $(x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1$ is not true, so quantifying over $\mathbb R$ (or over $\mathbb C$, or over $\mathbb Q$...) in this case is needed since you are using some properties of the operation in your structure (in this case, commutativity, associativity and $1\cdot x=x$) which could be false in another structure

Comment: what do you mean "construct some algebraic structure in which $(x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1$ is not true" ? How?

Comment: Well, for example you could have a structure where the operation $+$ is non-associative, so $x^2+2x+1$ wouldn't even make sense because $(x^2+2x)+1$ and $x^2+(2x+1)$ could have different values