# $x^2=4 \implies \exists x{=}2(x^2=4)$

Tags: analysis, logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

> $x^2=4 \implies x=2\tag1$
> $x^2=4 \implies \exists x{=}2(x^2=4)\tag2$

The first proposition is false, since it is logically equivalent to $x\neq2 \implies x^2\neq4$ which is obviously false.

It seems that the second proposition is also true. How can we prove it?

Comment: Minor quibble: the first statement is not “false”. Its truth depends on the value of $x$. It is true for any $x$ other than $x = -2$, and false for $x = -2$. If we add a $\forall x$ in front of the statement, it then becomes false.

Comment: Do you mean the domain of x? I should add $x \in \mathbb R$.  @MarkSaving

Comment: The first proposition is true for the natural numbers.  It is also true for plenty of infinite (and finite) subsets of the integers, rational numbers, real numbers, and complex numbers.  And yes, for those infinite subsets (x≠2)⟹ ((x^2)≠4).  For instance, consider the domain {..., -4, -3, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, ....} or all integers except '-2'.  I think according to set theory there are as many subdomains of the integers where the first proposition is true as there are subdomains of the integers where the first proposition is false.

Comment: From the perspective of classical philosophical logic, you have it reversed: that x^2 = 4 **presupposes** that there exists $x \in R$ such that (x^2 = 4). And a presupposition cannot be the consequent of an implication!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > $x^2=4 \implies \exists x{=}2(x^2=4)\tag2$

Statement $(2)$ is an (unusual) abbreviation of $$x^2=4 \implies \exists x \;(x=2\land x^2=4).$$ Putting $x=2$ shows that its consequent is (mathematically) true. Therefore, **statement $(2)$ is true**, regardless of whether its antecedent is true or false. In fact, statement $(2),$ which is [more clearly written as](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4594185/free-variables-and-bound-variables#comment9840953_4594185) $$x^2=4 \implies \exists y\; (y=2\land y^2=4),$$ is true regardless of how and whether it is quantified.

> > $x^2=4 \implies x=2\tag1$

Statement $(1)$ implicitly means $$\forall x\;(x^2=4 \implies x=2),$$ which is indeed false.

Comment: No, statement (1) is indeed true for plenty of infinite sets of the integers, rational numbers, real numbers, and complex numbers.  All that need hold true comes as that -2 does not belong to the set.  If my memory of how infinities work in set theory is correct, this implies that there are as many subsets of the integers for which it is true as subsets of integers for which it is false.  And, statement (1) is true for all subsets of the natural numbers.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood The OP tagged this post 'Analysis' and indicated (in comment #2) that the domain of discourse is $\mathbb R,$ so my answer like Mark Saving's comment above is in this context. Otherwise, we'd have to qualify, for example, that statement (2)'s consequent need not be true in an abstract algebra setting, and that statement (1) is true for the domain of discourse {2,4}.

Comment: I missed that comment.  Yes, it's *indeed* false.

Answer (score 0):

The proposition $\exists x=2(x^2=4)$ is short for $$ \exists x(x=2 \wedge x^2=4)$$

Thus, the second proposition is true. (The '$\wedge$' symbol means "and".)

Comment: Can you tell me why $\exists x=2(x^2=4)$ is short for $\exists x(x=2 \wedge x^2=4)$ ? Is this an convention for this equivalence?

Comment: Personally I have never come across the notation you are asking about. The fact that $\exists x=2(x^2=4)$ is short for $ \exists x(x=2 \wedge x^2=4)$ seems logical because in set theory there is, in fact, a standard shorthand for $\exists x(x\in y \wedge P(x))$, and it is $ \exists x\in y(P(x))$.

Comment: How do we prove they are logically equivalent? $\exists x(x\in y \wedge P(x))$ and $\exists x\in y(P(x))$.  Or Is it just obvious that we don't need to prove? Thank you so much!

Comment: It is a convention, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Try to interpret it in English. in the sense the second statement simply states "If $x^2=4$ then it implies there exists a $x = 2$ such that $x^2=4$".
Which is obviously true, as the statement speaks about being "a $x$" and not a "unique $x$"

Answer (score 0):

Given any propositions (or propositional functions $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$, the conditional $P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)$ is false when $P(x)$ is true and $Q(x)$ is false, otherwise $P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)$ is true.

Now let us put $P(x)$ to be the propositional function $x^2=4$ and $Q(x)$ be the propositional function $\exists x \left( x=2 \land x^2 = 4\right)$. Then as $Q(x)$ is true, so is $P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)$.

Comment: Given any propositions (or propositional functions $ P(x)$ and $Q(x)$, the conditional $P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)$ is false when $P(x)$ is true and $Q(x)$ is false, otherwise $P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)$ is true.

Now let us put $P(x)$ to be the propositional function $x^2=4$ and $Q(x)$ be the propositional function $\exists x \left( x=2 \land x^2 = 4\right)$. Then as $Q(x)$ is true, so is $P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)$.